# Parallel computing in R, summing variables

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm quite new to parallel computing in R and I would like (very simplified version of the original problem) to add a new value to X, Y and Z in the following way:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

X <- 0
Y <- 0
Z <- 0

cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1] - 1) #not to overload your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)
A <- foreach(i = 1:3, .combine = data.frame) %dopar% {
  X = X + i
  Y = Y + i + 2
  Z = Z + i + 3
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

I hoped to get `A = [6 12 15]` (6=1+2+3; 12=(1+2)+(2+2)+(3+2); 15=(1+3)+(2+3)+(3+3)), but unfortunately I get this result `A = [4 5 6]`.

I tried to solve this problem with the help of the documentation of foreach, and I think I should made a function myself for .combine to get the desired output, but I don't see how...

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the real problem behind this?

Comment: I need to do simulations and for each dataset I try (happens in parallel) I calculate for example  the squared difference between the real value and the estimated value, at the end I want to sum up these differences. But I have different measures :)

Answer (score 0):

Just found it myself! The following code returns the desired output

library(foreach)

library(doParallel)

X <- 0

Y = 0

Z = 0

cores=detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer

registerDoParallel(cl)

A= foreach(i = 1:3,.combine = '+') %dopar% {

X = X + i

Y = Y + i + 2

Z = Z + i + 3

return(c(X,Y,Z))

}

stopCluster(cl)